# Running commands in subdirectories with bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a sequence of directories that I need to run various shell commands on and I've made a short script called dodirs.sh to simplify running the command in each directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running in each directory: $@"
for d in ./*/; do
    (
    cd "$d"
    pwd
    eval "$@"
)
done
```

This is fine for many simple commands, but some have trouble, such as:

```
grep "free  energy   TOTEN" OUTCAR | tail -1
```

which looks for a string in a file located in each directory.

It seems that the pipe and/or the quotes is the trouble since if I say:

```
dodirs.sh grep "free  energy   TOTEN" OUTCAR
```

I get a sensible (if waaaay to long output) along the lines of:

```
Running in each directory: grep free  energy   TOTEN OUTCAR
...
OUTCAR:  free energy    TOTEN  =      -888.53122906 eV
OUTCAR:  free energy    TOTEN  =      -888.53132396 eV
OUTCAR:  free  energy   TOTEN  =      -888.531324 eV
...
```

I notice the result of the echo loses the quotes, so that is a bit odd.  On the other hand, if I say:

```
dodirs.sh grep "free  energy   TOTEN" OUTCAR | tail -1
```

then I get the nonsensical:

```
...
grep: energy: No such file or directory
grep: TOTEN: No such file or directory
...
```

Notice the echo doesn't echo at all now and it is clearly misinterpreting the line.

Is there some way I have to escape characters, or package the parameters inside my dodirs.sh script?

And maybe someone knows of a better approach altogether?

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: `eval "$@"` is a bit... counterintuitive. Generally speaking, you should either be taking a literal argv array, in which case you'd just use `"$@"` to execute it, or taking a single string, in which case you'd use `eval "$string"`.

Comment: ...the big advantage of the `eval "$string"` approach over `eval "$@"` is that a caller has to *know* it's in use to use it successfully -- they can't think they're calling something that goes the `execv` approach and instead be calling something that uses the `eval` approach, which is a common source of security bugs. (For instance, did you know that `ssh` uses the `eval` approach? Lots of folks don't, but if you don't know, you probably aren't taking the precautions to pass untrusted strings on a command line over SSH safely!)

Comment: ...btw, `.sh` extensions aren't universally considered good form for scripts (as opposed to libraries, for which an extension should reflect the specific interpreter needed -- thus, `.bash` for bash, `.ksh` for ksh, `.sh` for POSIX sh, etc). See http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh for the history of the factoid from the irc.freenode.org #bash channel on the topic (reflecting community consensus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
#!/bin/bash

# use printf %q to generate a command line identical to what we're actually doing
printf "Running in each directory: " >&2
printf '%q ' "$@" >&2
echo >&2

# use && -- we don't want to execute the command if cd into a given directory failed!
for d in ./*/; do
    (cd "$d" && echo "$PWD" >&2 && "$@")
done
```

This is much more predictable: It passes **exact** argument lists through, so for a general command you can just quote it naturally. (This is the exact same behavior as you get with `find -exec` or other tools which call `execv*`-family calls with a literal, passed-through argument list; thus, it means you get identical behavior to `sudo`, `chpst`, `chroot`, `setsid`, etc).

For a single command, invocation looks like what you'd expect:

```
dodirs grep "free  energy   TOTEN" OUTCAR
```

To execute shell directives, such as pipelines, explicitly execute a shell:

```
dodirs sh -c 'grep "free  energy   TOTEN" OUTCAR | tail -n 1'
#      ^^ ^^
```

...or, if you're willing to let callers rely on implementation details (such as the fact that this is implemented with a shell, and exactly *which* shell it's implemented with), use `eval`:

```
dodirs eval 'grep "free  energy   TOTEN" OUTCAR | tail -n 1'
#      ^^^^
```

This may be slightly more work, but it puts you in line with standard UNIX conventions, and avoids risking shell injection vulnerabilities if callers fail to quote their arguments to be `eval`-safe.

Comment: I tried this out and it does seem to work.  What does the >&2 mean?

Comment: `>&2` redirects to stderr, so that stdout is only containing output from the actual tool you're invoking. (stdout is supposed to be used for *output* only, whereas stderr is the right place for logs and such).

Comment: Ah!  OK.  I'm also not clear why I need to pass in the sh -c.  It is interpreting the entire single quoted region as a single argument to sh?  Why doesn't simply single quoting the grep + tail work?

Comment: `"$@"` literally takes your list of arguments, and [if there's no shell builtin or such matching the name] calls an `execv*`-family syscall with them -- an operating system directive that tells the kernel launch a separate executable with exactly those arguments. There's no shell involved in an `execv` operation unless you explicitly create or invoke one, so there's nothing to interpret any pipes, redirections, etc.

Comment: That's actually a feature, not a bug: If there's no shell interpreting content, then you don't need to worry about *how* a shell would interpret that content. You don't need to worry about whether a file has a malicious name, for instance, like one created with `touch '/tmp/$(rm -rf $HOME)'`, and whether that name would be interpreted: there's no shell, so no substitutions, so the risk gets avoided unless you intentionally create it (in which case you hopefully know what you're doing and how to handle untrusted content safely).

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks.  Finally, I notice the printf prints with escapes:  Running in each directory: bash -c grep\ \"free\ \ energy\ \ \ TOTEN\"\ OUTCAR\ \|\ tail\ -1     Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Also, if I put eval into the script, then I don't have to put eval on the command line.  But then I have to quote every command, whether it has the | tail -1 or not.

Comment: It's literally printing what you would need to copy-and-paste to have identical behavior. You could copy that `bash -c` command, cd into a directory by hand, paste it into your terminal, and it would do the exact same thing it does when run by this script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117135/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-zsg).

Answer (score 0):

The quotes disappear because they aren't necessary once the shell identifies the words to pass to your script as arguments. Inside your script, `$1` is `grep`, `$2` is `free  energy   TOTEN`, etc.

You do need to escape the pipe (with a backslash `\|` or by quoting `'|'`), though, so that it *also* is passed as an argument to `eval`.

```
dodirs.sh grep "free  energy   TOTEN" OUTCAR \| tail -1
```